# How to Perform Left Outer Join using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-6, left-join

I use the following code to select from Complaints' table and include other related tables.

```
Complaint complaint = await db.Complaints
            .Include(coy => coy.Company)
            .Include(c => c.Comments.Select(u => u.User))
            .Include(f => f.ComplaintFiles)
            .Include(u => u.User)
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(i => i.Id == id);
```

Users may want to post a complaint as anonymous. There's an anonymous field of boolean type in the complaints' table. So I would like user entity to return null for complaints posted as anonymous. 
How can I include user conditionally when the anonymous field in complaints' table is true?